# How to solve com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException The value is not set for the parameter number 5

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, database-connection, sql-server-express

The procedure runs smoothly when insterting just one SQLServerDataTable, or several simple params(like strings and integer), problem comes when I want to add more datatable parameters to send. here is the code Im using

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLServerException {

    SQLServerCallableStatement cstmt = null;
    SQLServerDataSource dataSource = new SQLServerDataSource();
    dataSource.setUser("sa");
    dataSource.setPassword("*********");
    dataSource.setServerName("localhost");
    dataSource.setInstanceName("SQLEXPRESS");
    dataSource.setDatabaseName("MaterialsDB2");
    Connection cone = dataSource.getConnection();

    SQLServerDataTable designationTable = new SQLServerDataTable();
    designationTable.addColumnMetadata("according_to", Types.VARCHAR);
    designationTable.addColumnMetadata("designation", Types.VARCHAR);

    designationTable.addRow("EN","5XCrTINi");
    designationTable.addRow("AISI","301");



    try  {

        cstmt = (SQLServerCallableStatement) cone.prepareCall("{call dbo.material_insertion(?,?,?,?,?)}");

        cstmt.setInt("Standard",1);
        cstmt.setInt("Family",1);
        cstmt.setString("Common_name","1.4310");
        cstmt.setString("Description","Well balanced material properties");

        cstmt.setStructured(1, "DesignationType", designationTable);

        boolean results = cstmt.execute();
        System.out.println(results);

    }
    // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}

Comment: I'd recommend setting all parameter using positions, not combining named with positional like you're doing right now.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel can you help me out with an example of how to set it using positions?